# How to compare time with AM PM in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two strings as follows:

var a = "11/24/2014 3:10 PM"
var b = "11/23/2014 7:45 AM"

How can I compare them with JavaScript, so that I could show that the time for var b happens before var a?

Comment: Parse the strings to date objects, then compare the timestamps.

Answer (score 4):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1duy5btm/39/)**

Convert the date stamp into UNIX time codes and then compare the two

```
var a = "11/24/2014 3:10 PM";
var b = "11/23/2014 7:45 AM";

var aDate = new Date(a).getTime();
var bDate = new Date(b).getTime();

if(aDate < bDate){
    console.log('a happened before b');
}else if (aDate > bDate){
    console.log('a happend after b');
}else{
    console.log('a and b happened at the same time')
}
```

Comment: glad to help, dont forget to mark an answer as accepted so future visitors can find the solution that helped you

Comment: Hi, quick question, does it matter at the conditional we prepare a and b versus aDate and bDate? Thanks!

Comment: nice one it saved my time :)

Comment: Question is about Am/PM but this answer does not even consider that. and it does work properly as well. try adding working jsfiddle / executable example

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla, while the question title uses the words AM/PM, OP's actual question was how to show that one time happened before another using date strings that include AM/PM. The jsfiddle is logging to the console; you'll need to open your developer tools in order to see the output :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to Parse dates to DateType take a look at following snippet

```js
var a = "11/24/2014 3:10 PM" 
b = "11/23/2014 7:45 AM"
var aDate= new Date(Date.parse(a));
var bDate = new Date(Date.parse(b));

if (aDate> bDate ){
  alert(aDate)   
}else{
  alert(bDate);       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This:-

```
function modify_time(){
    var start_time = "10:30 PM";
    var end_time = "12:30 PM";
    start_time = start_time.split(" ");
    var time = start_time[0].split(":");
    var stime = time[0];
    if(start_time[1] == "PM" && stime<12) stime = parseInt(stime) + 12;
    start_time = stime + ":" + time[1] + ":00";

    end_time = end_time.split(" ");
    var time1 = end_time[0].split(":");
    var etime = time1[0];
    if(end_time[1] == "PM" && etime<12) etime = parseInt(etime) + 12;
    end_time = etime + ":" + time1[1] + ":00";

    if (start_time != '' && end_time != '') { 
        alert(start_time);
        alert(end_time);
        if (end_time <= start_time) {
            alert('select valid time');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry wrong logic. it does not work. it tells 22:30 is less than 10:30

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code shared by Mohit Singh to make it perfect :

```
function checkTime() {
    var stime2 = '';
    var etime2 = '';
    if ($("#txtRequestTimeStart").val() != '' && $("#txtRequestTimeStop").val() != '') {
        var start_time = $("#txtRequestTimeStart").val();
        var end_time = $("#txtRequestTimeStop").val();
        start_time = start_time.split(" ");
        var time = start_time[0].split(":");
        var stime = time[0];
        
        if (stime.length == 1) {
            stime2 = "0" + stime;
            if (start_time[1] == "PM" && stime2 < 12) stime2 = parseInt(stime2) + 12;
            start_time = stime2 + ":" + time[1] + ":00";
        }
        else {
            if (start_time[1] == "PM" && stime < 12) stime = parseInt(stime) + 12;
            start_time = stime + ":" + time[1] + ":00";
        }

        end_time = end_time.split(" ");
        var time1 = end_time[0].split(":");
        var etime = time1[0];

        if (etime.length == 1) {
            etime2 = "0" + etime;
            if (end_time[1] == "PM" && etime2 < 12) etime2 = parseInt(etime2) + 12;
            end_time = etime2 + ":" + time1[1] + ":00";
        }
        else {
            if (end_time[1] == "PM" && etime < 12) etime = parseInt(etime) + 12;
            end_time = etime + ":" + time1[1] + ":00";
        }
                    
        if (start_time != '' && end_time != '') {
            if (end_time <= start_time) {
                alert('Begin Time should not be greater than or equal to End Time');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).